# How do I continue do things after finish footable initialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, footable

I use query plugin named fooTable for my data table (http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/)

Below is my code to initialize my datatable...

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.table').footable({
      "paging": { "size": 15 },
      // "toggleColumn": "last",
      "showToggle": false,
      "columns": $.get('/footable/js/columns.json'),
      "rows": $.get('/footable/js/rows.json')
  })
})
```

My question is how to do something after it finished initialize?

I try

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.table').footable({
      "paging": { "size": 15 },
      // "toggleColumn": "last",
      "showToggle": false,
      "columns": $.get('/footable/js/columns.json'),
      "rows": $.get('/footable/js/rows.json')
  })
  .done(function(){
    alert('do something');
  })
})
```

But it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `postinit.ft.table` event. See http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/jsdocs/FooTable.html#.event:Table%2522postinit.ft.table%2522

> The postinit.ft.table event is raised after any components are initialized but before the table is drawn for the first time. Calling preventDefault on this event will disable the initial drawing of the table.

Also, `postdraw.ft.table` is what you may want.

#### About how to use it

I am not very familiar to it. So give it a try. If it doesn't work tell me.

```
.when('postinit.ft.table', function(e, ft){
    //ok
})
```

Comment: How do i use this event?

Comment: @aBloomer answer is modified. see it

Comment: Really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `postinit.ft.table` event along with the [`on`](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#on) option as mentioned by @Roamer-1888. (You can click on any option to see a small example of how to use it.)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.table').footable({
        // your other options
        'on': {
            'postinit.ft.table': function(e, ft) {
                /*
                 * e: The jQuery.Event object for the event.
                 * ft: The instance of the plugin raising the event.
                 */
                // all initialized - do stuff here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively the second argument to the plugin constructor is a ready callback so you can just provide a function to execute once everything is done.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.table').footable({
        // your options
    }, function(ft){
        /*
         * ft: The instance of the plugin raising the event.
         */
        // all initialized - do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: I was unable to get anything working throughout all of these answers except for the last option here with the second argument, for anyone else looking to do stuff after everything is initialized this is what you will want.

Comment: Also, there's a `ready.ft.table` event, useful in this cases.

Answer (score 1):

The FooTable documentation is difficult to follow as it's not over-endowed with examples.

I think @turle's suggestion to use the "postinit.ft.table" event is a good one, however I can't see that `.when('postinit.ft.table', function(e, ft){ /* do something */ })` is the right syntax.

As far as I can gather from [here](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html), event handlers are attached using the "on" option.

Try :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.table').footable({
        'paging': { 'size': 15 },
        // "toggleColumn': "last",
        'showToggle': false,
        'columns': $.get('/footable/js/columns.json'),
        'rows': $.get('/footable/js/rows.json'),
        'on': {
            'postinit.ft.table': function(e, ft) {
                /*
                 * e: The jQuery.Event object for the event.
                 * ft: The instance of the plugin raising the event.
                 */
                // all initialized - do stuff here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try 'ready.ft.table'

Something like

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable({
    "on": {
        "ready.ft.table": function(e, ft){
            // bind to the plugin initialize event to do something
        }
    }
   });
});
```